# which data structure in java will be the best to implement the following concept?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am currently working on web data extraction.. I would like to associate certain fields to nodes generated in the DOM tree namely, a vector of integer values, two integer fields and pointers to child nodes.. I have to do bottom up traversal of the constructed tree to do certain computation. I would like to know which data structure will be the  best to implement the above mentioned concept??

I thought of implementing as m-tree. I have arrived at a node structure in C++.
C++ node structure

```
class SFVT {
    struct fnode{
        Node n; //DOM tree node
        Vector<int> sfv;
        int no_times;
        int val; 
        struct fnode *ptr[];
    } 
};
```

Comment: If you are n-ary nodes for a single parent the TRIE data structure will be best to use